# When to use CoProcess Function in Flink?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am just trying to understand the use case when to use CoProcessFunction in Flink. Explanation with an example would help me to understand the concept better.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A CoProcessFunction is similar to a RichCoFlatMap, but with the addition of also being able to use timers. The timers are useful for expiring state for stale keys, or for raising alarms when keep alive messages fail to arrive, for example.

A CoProcessFunction allows you to use one stream to influence how another is processed, or to enrich another stream. For example, an e-commerce site might have a stream of order events and a stream of shipment events, and they want to create a stream of events for orders that haven't shipped with 24 hours of the order being placed. The two streams can be keyed by the orderId, and connected together. As an order arrives it's recorded in keyed state, and a timer is created to fire 24 hours later. When a shipment event arrives, the state and timer are cleared. If a timer does fire, the state is used to send the order out to the unfilled order service.

For more on this, and examples with code, see [connected streams](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/learn-flink/etl/#connected-streams) and [process function](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/learn-flink/event_driven/) and the labs that accompany those tutorials.

Comment: The links for the above connected streams and process function example  look damaged, could you please provide the updated ones. Thanks.

Comment: @Mazen The links are fixed; thanks for pointing out the problem.

Comment: The links are damaged again, can you please update them ?

Comment: Done, sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: @DavidAnderson The link is broken again. Is it possible to fix this or possible to share the sample code in the answer, please?

Comment: I fixed the links. The amount of content involved is rather large, so copying it here doesn't make a lot of sense, in my opinion.

Comment: the example given there doesnt filter at all.
it just prints everything, Am I missing something here ?

It works as expected when  env.setParallelism(1); what am I missing here ?