# Is there a way to combine two ProcessFunction into one in Flink?

Tags: java, stream, apache-flink

I want two combine two `ProcessFunction` into one like `Function.andThen(Function)`.

Is there a way to achieve this?
Can't find any solutions. Need some help.

Answer (score 0):

If you do

```java
stream
  .process(a)
  .process(b)
```

then `b` will be applied to the output of `a`. If this isn't what you are looking for, please elaborate.

Comment: I want to make them one ProcessFunction. Not two.

Comment: Perhaps that could be done with a custom operator, but it would be ugly. Can I ask what motivates you to want this? Perhaps there's a better solution to the underlying problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
stream.join(otherStream)
    .where(<KeySelector>)
    .equalTo(<KeySelector>)
    .window(<WindowAssigner>)
    .apply(<JoinFunction>)
```

you can have a look here too [When to use CoProcess Function in Flink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57236242/when-to-use-coprocess-function-in-flink)